# Convert string to Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

I've received a flat file and after parsing and inserting it in a table. I've a column which has dates in a format **yyyyMMddhhmmss**

Here, **yyyy** is year, **MM** is month, **dd** is day, **hh** is hours, **mm** is minute and **ss** is seconds part

I'm trying to convert this to DateTime type as mentioned below but not working for me

```
SELECT CAST(StrDate as DateTime) FROM [dbo].[Mytable]
```

For example: 
Column has a value `20150121190941` in `Varchar` format and it should be converted to `DateTime` as **2015-01-21 19:09:41.000**

I apologize if it's a duplicate one.

Comment: Provide sample and expected output data for this.

Comment: How do you parse it? Cant you convert it there and insert it as `DateTime`? F.e. with C#: `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20150121190941", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: That's my question. I want that string to insert into a column of type  `DateTime` . That's possible only after conversion from `NVARCHAR(20)` to `DateTime`.

Comment: @M.S., have you considered using a datetime data type for the table column and parsing it into a native type before insert?  That will avoid the T-SQL conversion ugliness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds )

```
declare @dt nvarchar(25) = '20150121190941'

select datetimefromparts(left(@dt,4), substring(@dt,5,2), substring(@dt,7,2),substring(@dt,9,2), substring(@dt,11,2), substring(@dt,13,2), '000')
```

Comment: Thanks but I need time part as well

Comment: Yes use datetimefromparts.. which will give with time

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server readily recognizes YYYYMMDD as a date.  So, converting the first 8 characters to a date is easy.  Alas, I don't think there is a time representation without colons.

So, here is one rather brutal method:

```
select (convert(datetime, left(StrDate, 8)) +
        convert(time, substring(StrDate, 9, 2 ) + ':' + substring(StrDate, 11, 2 ) + ':' + substring(StrDate, 13, 2 )
               )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare @dt varchar(50)
set @dt=20150121190941

create table tblDateTbl
( 
    col1 datetime
)
insert into dt (col1)
select SUBSTRING(@dt,1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@dt,5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@dt,7,2)+ ' ' + SUBSTRING(@dt,9,2)+ ':' + SUBSTRING(@dt,11,2)+ ':' + SUBSTRING(@dt,13,2)+ '.000'

Comment: I just provided sample data, you need to replace @dt with your column name and use update statement.